# Вызов функции по таймеру

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как нужно правильно вызывать функцию с периодичностью в 2 секунды? Я делал так:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var json = ajax_query();
    view_data(json);
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 2000);
}, 2000);

function ajax_query() {
    jQuery.ajax({
    url:"/model.php",
    type:"POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(result) {
        return result;
    });
}
```

После этого выполнялся php код, и я выходе я получал готовый `json`, который попадал в функцию `view_data()` и отображался на экране. 
НО!!! Проблема в следующем - этот таймер работает постоянно, и во время его работы не работает больше ничего. Целью же этого таймера есть следующая идея: Есть чат, и что бы пользователь видел обновление сообщений - производится подгрузка сообщений каждые 2 секунды. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне исправить код, что бы таймер работал и другие скрипты тоже выполнялись?

Comment: для чатов больше подходит websocket вместо ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема может быть вызвана тем, что вы планируете новый таймер еще до завершения ответа от сервера. Попробуйте так:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var callee = arguments.callee;
    ajax_query(function(json) {
        view_data(json);
        setTimeout(callee, 2000);        
    });
}, 2000);

function ajax_query(success) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/model.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success:success
    });
}
```

Возможно, вам понадобится еще ускорить вызов вашего model.php.

И websocket хорошо бы использовать, если браузер поддерживает. Если же нет, то по старинке AJAX/COMET.